# Using cvFindContour with cvMinAreaRect2

Tags: opencv

I succeeded in using cvDrawContour but when I try to use cvMinRectArea2, it only shows one dot. Any ideas? Here's the source code.

```
         IplImage *src = cvLoadImage("SignImg.jpg",0);

         IplImage *dst_img = 0;
         IplImage *img = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(src),8,3);
         CvBox2D rect;

        CvMemStorage *storage = cvCreateMemStorage ();
         CvSeq *contours = 0;

        char a[255];
        sprintf(&a[0],"%s",openFileDialog1->FileName);

        dst_img = cvLoadImage(a,0);

        cvFindContours (src, storage, &contours, sizeof(CvContour), CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE ,cvPoint(0,0));          

        cvCvtColor(dst_img,img,CV_GRAY2BGR);

        cvDrawContours (img, contours, CV_RGB(255,0,0), cvScalarAll(255),1,1,8,cvPoint(0,0));
        rect=cvMinAreaRect2 (contours,0);
        cvEllipseBox(img,rect,cvScalarAll(0),5,8,0);
```

Comment: In that way you are drawing only the first contour that is obtained in the image. You should draw it on a separate blank image to see also if it doesn't overlay on another part that has the same color, in so making it invisible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right way to use [cvDrawContours](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/drawing_functions.html#drawcontours) is shown here:

```
    for( ; contour != 0; contour = contour->h_next )
    {
        CvScalar color = CV_RGB( rand()&255, rand()&255, rand()&255 );

        /* replace CV_FILLED with 1 to see the outlines */
        cvDrawContours( dst, contour, color, color, -1, CV_FILLED, 8 );
    }
```

If it's not obvious enough, your variable `contours` is an array and you need to iterate over it and draw each element! Else you will be drawing only the first element of the array.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I need to draw a rect around the dots. How do i box them?